# NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.url

Tags: python, django

I tried all the failed solutions I could've found. 
I have deleted the migration files and ran makemigrations/migrate
I have migration file with `__init__.py`
but none of them works...
I really have no idea what's wrong.
My guess is something in db got messed up, but I have deleted and recovered it and same error shows up.

> Full error message is: IntegrityError at /add_post/
>
> NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.url

Here is my code, any help would be super appreicated.

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = FroalaField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    objects = models.Manager()            # default manager


    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    @property
    def url(self):
        if self.link:
            return self.link
        return current_request().build_absolute_uri(self.get_absolute_url())


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 


    # for redirecting URL so slug is always shown
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/%s/%s' % (self.id, self.slug)
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")

    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200,
                         help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'views', 'category', 'url']
```

I have title,content,views fields but chosing not to write them here.

pretty sure nothing's wrong with my views.py, but just in case

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is my moderator

```
moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

what is this NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.moderator_id...what does not null constraint mean/

Comment: What does your DB schema for table "post" looks like (not your django model - the schema at the database level) ? I bet my 2 pence that it doesn't match the django model wrt/ allowing null.

Comment: Sounds like the `url` field might initially not allow null, but you changed it later. The migration would only check the model level change based on previous migration file and current model code, but it won't look at database at all.

Comment: @ShangWang just tried it, it gives me same error

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers just tried without null, gives me same error when I'm about to create post

Comment: No, what I meant is that your migration files might be messed up. If all the migrations are still in the dev environment, you could delete your database and migrations and create again. If your previous migrations are already in production, you need to roll back your url field to what previous state looks like(null=False), then create new migration file.

Comment: @Alasdair, yes I saw that solution so I dropped it and ran migration but it won't work. what I did was deleted every file in migration folder except for __init__.py and ran python manage.py makemigrations and migrate

Comment: @ShangWang ok, let me try deleteing my migration files again

Comment: @ I just dropped my whole db files, had to create whole thing. then it gives me same type of error: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_post.moderator_id.

Comment: @Alasdair...whered you go

Comment: @ShangWang, please help....what's wrong with this....

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you showed the entire `Post` model. It seems that you have `moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)` in your `Post` model, but you are not setting the `moderator` in your view so you get the `NOT NULL constraint failed error`. What do you want the moderator to be set to? The logged in user?

Comment: @Alasdair, I will upload my post model. yes I have that in the model. what do you mean set moderator in my view? Yes, I want the moderator to be logged in user. For the temporary solution I put blank and null to be true but they shouldn't be because I want moderator to be logged in user

Comment: @Alasdair I edited just like you requested....

Comment: I think you are now getting an IntegrityError on the `slug` field, which is the only not-NULL field without a default value, and you never set it.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini hmm how do you suppose i fix the error

Comment: just set the slug :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I already did  slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
but it doesn't work

Comment: that way you are declaring the field. What you need to to is setting a value for it. Either expose the field in your form (`fields = [..., 'slug']`) or set it in your view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the `moderator` to the logged in user, you can do this is your view's `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.moderator = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
```

Once you have done this, you will no longer need `null=True` for the `moderator` field.

Comment: so add the following method to the my models.py, insdie class Post right? and remove null and blank =true for moderator?

Comment: The `form_valid` method is for your `PostCreateView`. Once the view is working, you'll be able to remove `null=True,  blank=True` from the field.